# Nginx reverse proxy deeplinks Wordpress on Docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to run Wordpress on Digital Ocean through Docker. Things started out well, I had it up and running in no time configured like so:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    wordpress:
        depends_on:
            - db
        image: wordpress:5.5.1-php7.2-apache
        container_name: wp
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./www/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PWD}
        ports:
            - 3010:80
        networks:
            - network
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        container_name: db
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PWD}
        networks:
            - network
    phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
            - db
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: pma
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 3011:80
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: db
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PWD}
            UPLOAD_LIMIT: 20000000
        networks:
            - network
networks:
    network:
volumes:
    db_data:
```

On the Digital Ocean droplet I configured Nginx as a reverse proxy:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name my.test.url;

    location / {
        rewrite /(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3010;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

I already had my.test.url pointing to the droplet's IP.
I updated the 'siteurl' and 'home' records in the wp_options table in the database to my.test.url

This all worked well, serving the homepage if I visit my.test.url. However when I visit a deep link, like my.test.url/example I get redirected to 127.0.0.1/example where obviously nothing is running.

I don't know how to proceed; I thought setting the rewrite rule in the nginx config would do the trick but alas..

I should mention I want to run multiple sites on the Digital Ocean droplet, each serving from their own port, so 'just' serving from port 80 is not an option.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the above configuration was correct; the problem was a DNS error combined with Wordpress permalink settings that dictated a trailing slash after the post name. This caused a DNS lookup on the server that failed, resulting in the redirect to 127.0.0.1...